# Php Json Web service Error

Tags: php, json

I am having an issue with a JSON web service I created with php. Keep getting garbage within my JSON when I include the line echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($posts).')'; added to that am getting an error unidentified index on line (some number) but its the line that echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($posts).')'; appears.

If i leave that line out I get JSON but end up with an error of invalid label

how can I solve this issue? My code is below.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('music_db',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

/* grab the posts from the db */
$query = "SELECT track.track_id, track.track_name, artist.artist_name, genre.genre_name FROM artist INNER JOIN (genre INNER JOIN track ON genre.genre_id = track.genre_id) ON artist.artist_id = track.artist_id";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

/* create one master array of the records */
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
 }
}

/* output in necessary format */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
@mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a notice because the index you are trying to use is not set. You need to check for it before using it.

```
if(isset($_GET['jsoncallback'])) {
  // Code here
}
```

Comment: You use the check before you output this `$_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($posts).')';` If its not set, then you fallback to just outputting the json directly.

Comment: therefore you are saying to do this `if(isset($_GET['jsoncallback'])) {
  $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($posts).')';
} else { what do I put here then? }`

Comment: You would echo the json output without trying to prepend the callback function.

Comment: ok i am lost as to what you mean can u give an example please